# How to add a Facebook page-plugin on to Weebly?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, weebly, facebook-feed

I have tried this code already by copying both portions into the 'embed code' widget and all that came up was the name 'Perfectly Posh'.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Perfectly-Posh/765054396873623" data-width="300" data-height="500" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Perfectly-Posh/765054396873623"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Perfectly-Posh/765054396873623">Perfectly Posh</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I then tried another code in a different embed code widget that used iframe, but all I get is the top of the Facebook page. I actually believe the Facebook page works, but just that it is hidden somehow.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPerfectly-Posh%2F765054396873623&width=600&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=435" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:600px; height:430px; background: white; float:left; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Lastly, I tried the Feed Reader widget and I got an error. The feed does actually work, just not on Weebly.

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=765054396873623
```

Comment: Test in other browsers and/or disable extensions. For me "all that came up was the name" happened when I had an extension installed in Firefox which blocked tracking cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook social plugin doesn't work on iframe. This is actually a old question.

Answer (score 0):

fill "your `weebly` link" into `data-href=""`

```js
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://yoursubdomain.weebly.com" data-width="550" data-overflow="auto" data-numposts="75"></div>
```

It worked on my free-site `wen.ru & weebly`
http://furay.fiz.su/forum/
http://amandannyaman.weebly.com/forum.html

Hope that help!